# Create new process or use Start cmdlet in Powershell

Tags: powershell, process

I was messing around with a script that I found on the internet that will check to see if you are running the current Powershell console under the Admin role and, if not, start a new instance of Powershell and close the former window.

*The part that checks it isn't really the issue, I just have a question on how it starts a new instance of Powershell.*

This is how it is performed in the script:

```
$newProcess = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "Powershell";
$newProcess.Arguments = "& '" + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name + "'"
$newProcess.Verb = "runas";
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess);
Exit;
```

This is a rather well-known and regularly used script (empirically, it is scattered all over the web in myriad websites).

As most Powershell-savvy folks know, you can bring up Powershell and have it run as Administrator from the command line (within a Run prompt, Command shell, & Powershell) by typing:

```
Start Powershell -ArgumentList "& '$scriptpath'" -Verb runas
```

And anyone that is familiar with scripting can see that these will do the exact same thing--they even seem to resemble each other!

**Between these two ways of starting a new instance of Powershell and running a called script, what are the differences? Which is recommended and which is not? Is one more correct (appropriate) than the other?**

As I am self-taught and I generally learn as I go, best practices, advice, and what is deprecated\superseded is often overlooked.

I don't really have a background in the .NET framework or C#, so, if the answer is obvious from that standpoint, you'll have to forgive me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Start` is an alias for [`Start-Process`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx), which is basically a wrapper around `[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start` (it actually returns a [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) object). You can use either of them, but the former is more PoSh since its syntax follows PowerShell conventions.

See also [this comprehensive Technet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx) for an overview of ways to run executables from PowerShell.